# Hbase-Sharp Throws "System.OutofMemoryException"

Tags: c#, hbase

I am using Hbase-Sharp project DLL to Connect to Hbase from my C# code, but I am getting:

```
Cannot read, Remote side has closed
```

But the socket is already connected to the specified Host and Port. 
Did anybody face this issue? Also, does Hbase-sharp fit good for Production environment?

Comment: Somebody Please reply !

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Also, have you got any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its bit late but the resolution can help anyone. Thanks Chazt3n for reminding me.
The out of memory exception while using Hbase-Sharp DLL signifies that you are not using the right version of C# generated code with your program. Its kind of version mismatch between your host program and referred Hbase-Sharp DLL. Hope this helps.